# Ripping DVD with HandBrake, no file found during scan

Tags: dvd, handbrake, disk-ripping

I'm trying to rip a DVD with HandBrake (I own the original). No single file is found during the scan despite having installed the libdvdcss4 package. There are several errors occurring in the activity report, including that no data could be read. I have no idea how to fix this or what packages could be missing. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
    [19:18:28] gtkgui: HandBrake rev0 (2013082899) - Linux x86_64 - http://handbrake.fr
    [19:18:28] hb_init: starting libhb thread
    [19:18:28] hb_init: starting libhb thread
    libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
    [19:18:35] hb_scan: CPU count: 4
    [19:18:35] hb_scan: CPU name:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz
    [19:18:35] hb_scan: CPU type:  Intel microarchitecture Sandy Bridge
    [19:18:35] hb_scan: path=/media/AMERICANBEAUTY/VIDEO_TS, title_index=0
    libbluray/bdnav/index_parse.c:162: indx_parse(): error opening /media/AMERICANBEAUTY/VIDEO_TS/BDMV/index.bdmv
    libbluray/bdnav/index_parse.c:162: indx_parse(): error opening /media/AMERICANBEAUTY/VIDEO_TS/BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
    libbluray/bluray.c:1725: nav_get_title_list(/media/AMERICANBEAUTY/VIDEO_TS) failed (0x7f6350003690)
    [19:18:35] bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead
    libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.1.3
    libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
    libdvdread: Attempting to use device /dev/sr0 mounted on /media/AMERICANBEAUTY for CSS authentication
    libdvdnav: Can't read name block. Probably not a DVD-ROM device.
    libdvdnav: Unable to find map file '/home/timbo/.dvdnav/.map'
    libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2

    libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
    libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x00000138
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB at 0x000002f0
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x000003a4
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_0.VOB at 0x00002191
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB at 0x00002245
    libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB (0x00002245)!!
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_0.VOB at 0x000b4647
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB at 0x000b4df3
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_0.VOB at 0x0032fadf
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_1.VOB at 0x0032fb93
    libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_1.VOB (0x0032fb93)!!
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 1
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_0.VOB at 0x00398f16
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_1.VOB at 0x00398fca
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_0.VOB at 0x00398fe2
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_1.VOB at 0x00399096
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
    libdvdread: Found 6 VTS's
    libdvdread: Elapsed time 1
    libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
    libdvdread: Attempting to use device /dev/sr0 mounted on /media/AMERICANBEAUTY for CSS authentication
    [19:18:36] scan: DVD has 7 title(s)
    [19:18:36] scan: scanning title 1
    [19:18:36] scan: opening IFO for VTS 3
    [19:18:36] scan: duration is 01:56:38 (6998520 ms)
    [19:18:36] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f63500126f0
    [19:18:36] scan: vts=3, ttn=1, cells=0->29, blocks=0->2600112, 2600113 blocks
    [19:18:36] scan: checking audio 1
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:36] scan: checking audio 2
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0x81bd, lang=Deutsch (AC3), 3cc=deu ext=1
    [19:18:36] scan: checking audio 3
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0x82bd, lang=English (AC3) (Director's Commentary 1), 3cc=eng ext=3
    [19:18:36] scan: checking audio 4
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0xa3bd, lang=English (LPCM), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:36] scan: checking subtitle 1
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0x22bd, lang=English (Closed Caption), 3cc=eng ext=5
    [19:18:36] scan: checking subtitle 2
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0x23bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=1
    [19:18:36] scan: title 1 has 29 chapters
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->103689 (103690), 252680 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=103690->226193 (122504), 339840 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 3 c=2->2, b=226194->311794 (85601), 204000 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 4 c=3->3, b=311795->430718 (118924), 300000 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 5 c=4->4, b=430719->521330 (90612), 274760 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 6 c=5->5, b=521331->581953 (60623), 150200 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 7 c=6->6, b=581954->658201 (76248), 203960 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 8 c=7->7, b=658202->780663 (122462), 335680 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 9 c=8->8, b=780664->864913 (84250), 232280 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 10 c=9->9, b=864914->921665 (56752), 151400 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 11 c=10->10, b=921666->989555 (67890), 211080 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 12 c=11->11, b=989556->1079573 (90018), 224400 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 13 c=12->12, b=1079574->1110982 (31409), 76520 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 14 c=13->13, b=1110983->1193851 (82869), 235600 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 15 c=14->15, b=1193852->1303504 (109653), 248240 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 16 c=16->16, b=1303505->1412041 (108537), 300560 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 17 c=17->17, b=1412042->1499454 (87413), 243720 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 18 c=18->18, b=1499455->1581097 (81643), 241560 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 19 c=19->19, b=1581098->1675922 (94825), 249480 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 20 c=20->20, b=1675923->1790579 (114657), 320640 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 21 c=21->21, b=1790580->1872953 (82374), 201960 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 22 c=22->22, b=1872954->2008297 (135344), 332640 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 23 c=23->23, b=2008298->2129096 (120799), 347840 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 24 c=24->24, b=2129097->2205915 (76819), 215640 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 25 c=25->25, b=2205916->2344107 (138192), 362840 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 26 c=26->26, b=2344108->2402113 (58006), 177160 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 27 c=27->27, b=2402114->2498637 (96524), 238320 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 28 c=28->28, b=2498638->2600106 (101469), 325000 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 29 c=29->29, b=2600107->2600112 (6), 520 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: aspect = 1.77778
    [19:18:36] scan: scanning title 2
    [19:18:36] scan: opening IFO for VTS 1
    [19:18:36] scan: duration is 00:00:24 (24600 ms)
    [19:18:36] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f63500131b0
    [19:18:36] scan: vts=1, ttn=1, cells=0->1, blocks=0->7625, 7626 blocks
    [19:18:36] scan: checking audio 1
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:36] scan: checking audio 2
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0xa1bd, lang=English (LPCM), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:36] scan: title 2 has 2 chapters
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->7619 (7620), 24000 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=7620->7625 (6), 600 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: aspect = 1.77778
    [19:18:36] scan: scanning title 3
    [19:18:36] scan: opening IFO for VTS 4
    [19:18:36] scan: duration is 00:22:01 (1321600 ms)
    [19:18:36] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f6350020910
    [19:18:36] scan: vts=4, ttn=1, cells=0->1, blocks=0->430953, 430954 blocks
    [19:18:36] scan: checking audio 1
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:36] scan: checking audio 2
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0xa1bd, lang=English (LPCM), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:36] scan: checking subtitle 1
    [19:18:36] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:36] scan: title 3 has 2 chapters
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->430947 (430948), 1321000 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=430948->430953 (6), 600 ms
    [19:18:36] scan: aspect = 1.33333
    [19:18:36] scan: scanning title 4
    [19:18:36] scan: opening IFO for VTS 5
    [19:18:36] scan: duration is 00:00:00 (600 ms)
    [19:18:36] scan: ignoring title (too short)
    [19:18:36] scan: scanning title 5
    [19:18:36] scan: opening IFO for VTS 6
    [19:18:37] scan: duration is 00:01:07 (67600 ms)
    [19:18:37] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f6350021340
    [19:18:37] scan: vts=6, ttn=1, cells=0->1, blocks=0->20992, 20993 blocks
    [19:18:37] scan: checking audio 1
    [19:18:37] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:37] scan: checking audio 2
    [19:18:37] scan: id=0xa1bd, lang=English (LPCM), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:37] scan: title 5 has 2 chapters
    [19:18:37] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->20986 (20987), 67000 ms
    [19:18:37] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=20987->20992 (6), 600 ms
    [19:18:37] scan: aspect = 1.77778
    [19:18:37] scan: scanning title 6
    [19:18:37] scan: opening IFO for VTS 6
    [19:18:37] scan: duration is 00:02:53 (173600 ms)
    [19:18:37] pgc_id: 2, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f63500221d0
    [19:18:37] scan: vts=6, ttn=2, cells=0->1, blocks=20993->77013, 56021 blocks
    [19:18:37] scan: checking audio 1
    [19:18:37] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:37] scan: checking audio 2
    [19:18:37] scan: id=0xa1bd, lang=English (LPCM), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:37] scan: title 6 has 2 chapters
    [19:18:37] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=20993->77007 (56015), 173000 ms
    [19:18:37] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=77008->77013 (6), 600 ms
    [19:18:37] scan: aspect = 1.77778
    [19:18:37] scan: scanning title 7
    [19:18:37] scan: opening IFO for VTS 2
    [19:18:37] scan: duration is 01:01:25 (3685600 ms)
    [19:18:37] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f6350021f90
    [19:18:37] scan: vts=2, ttn=1, cells=0->2, blocks=0->730044, 730045 blocks
    [19:18:37] scan: checking audio 1
    [19:18:37] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:37] scan: checking audio 2
    [19:18:37] scan: id=0xa1bd, lang=English (LPCM), 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:37] scan: checking subtitle 1
    [19:18:37] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=1
    [19:18:37] scan: title 7 has 2 chapters
    [19:18:37] scan: chap 1 c=0->1, b=0->730038 (730039), 3685000 ms
    [19:18:37] scan: chap 2 c=2->2, b=730039->730044 (6), 600 ms
    [19:18:37] scan: aspect = 1.33333
    libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
    [19:18:37] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:38] scan: decoding previews for title 1
    libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
    [19:18:38] scan: title angle(s) 1
    [19:18:38] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:38] Last error repeated 4 times
    [19:18:38] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:38] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
    [19:18:38] Warning: Could not read data for preview 2, skipped
    [19:18:38] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:38] Warning: Could not read data for preview 3, skipped
    [19:18:39] Warning: Could not read data for preview 4, skipped
    [19:18:39] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:39] Warning: Could not read data for preview 5, skipped
    [19:18:39] Warning: Could not read data for preview 6, skipped
    [19:18:39] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:39] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:39] Last error repeated 5 times
    [19:18:39] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:39] Warning: Could not read data for preview 7, skipped
    [19:18:39] Warning: Could not read data for preview 8, skipped
    [19:18:39] Warning: Could not read data for preview 9, skipped
    [19:18:40] Warning: Could not read data for preview 10, skipped
    [19:18:40] scan: decoding previews for title 2
    libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
    [19:18:40] scan: title angle(s) 1
    [19:18:40] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:40] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
    [19:18:40] Warning: Could not read data for preview 2, skipped
    [19:18:40] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:40] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:40] Last error repeated 5 times
    [19:18:40] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:40] Warning: Could not read data for preview 3, skipped
    [19:18:40] Warning: Could not read data for preview 4, skipped
    [19:18:40] Warning: Could not read data for preview 5, skipped
    [19:18:40] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:40] Last error repeated 1 times
    [19:18:40] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
    [19:18:40] Warning: Could not read data for preview 6, skipped
    [19:18:41] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:41] Warning: Could not read data for preview 7, skipped
    [19:18:41] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:41] Warning: Could not read data for preview 8, skipped
    [19:18:41] Warning: Could not read data for preview 9, skipped
    [19:18:41] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:41] Warning: Could not read data for preview 10, skipped
    [19:18:41] scan: decoding previews for title 3
    libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
    [19:18:41] scan: title angle(s) 1
    [19:18:41] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:41] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
    [19:18:42] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:42] Warning: Could not read data for preview 2, skipped
    [19:18:42] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:42] Last error repeated 4 times
    [19:18:42] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
    [19:18:42] scan: decoding previews for title 5
    libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
    [19:18:42] scan: title angle(s) 1
    [19:18:42] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:42] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
    [19:18:42] Last error repeated 6 times
    [19:18:42] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:42] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
    [19:18:42] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:42] Warning: Could not read data for preview 2, skipped
    [19:18:42] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:42] Warning: Could not read data for preview 3, skipped
    [19:18:42] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:42] Warning: Could not read data for preview 4, skipped
    [19:18:42] Warning: Could not read data for preview 5, skipped
    [19:18:43] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:43] Warning: Could not read data for preview 6, skipped
    [19:18:43] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:43] Last error repeated 4 times
    [19:18:43] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
    [19:18:43] Warning: Could not read data for preview 7, skipped
    [19:18:43] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:43] Warning: Could not read data for preview 8, skipped
    [19:18:43] Warning: Could not read data for preview 9, skipped
    [19:18:43] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:43] Warning: Could not read data for preview 10, skipped
    [19:18:43] scan: decoding previews for title 6
    libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
    [19:18:43] scan: title angle(s) 1
    [19:18:43] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:43] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
    [19:18:43] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:43] Last error repeated 2 times
    [19:18:43] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
    [19:18:43] Warning: Could not read data for preview 2, skipped
    [19:18:44] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:44] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:44] Warning: Could not read data for preview 3, skipped
    [19:18:44] Warning: Could not read data for preview 4, skipped
    [19:18:44] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:44] Warning: Could not read data for preview 5, skipped
    [19:18:44] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:44] Warning: Could not read data for preview 6, skipped
    [19:18:44] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:44] Last error repeated 2 times
    [19:18:44] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
    [19:18:44] scan: decoding previews for title 7
    libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
    [19:18:44] scan: title angle(s) 1
    [19:18:44] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
    [19:18:45] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (00000000)
    [19:18:45] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
    [19:18:45] Last error repeated 3 times
    [19:18:45] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
    [19:18:45] Warning: Could not read data for preview 2, skipped
    [19:18:45] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
    [19:18:45] libhb: scan thread found 0 valid title(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

I searched many forums and also tried what was suggested here.

My problems with HandBrake in trying to rip a DVD pointed towards a misinstalled libdvdcss.

I found out, while reading the README file in `/usr/share/doc/libdvd-pkg` that it is possible to run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

....in order to recompile the package for your specific installation.

Maybe this will help you too.

Comment: This helped me; on Ubuntu 23.04 the readme is in `/usr/share/doc/libdvdread8/README.css` btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `sudo sh /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` in Terminal (<kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

As for handbrake on valid source found, possible reasons on this:

1. The DVD disc has been damaged/ scratched or it is copy-protected;
2. Handbrake version is outdated;

To resolve this problem, you can:

1. get another DVD ripper that can rip scratched DVDs or copy-protected DVDs;
2. update handbrake to the latest version;
3. install libdvdcss to convert CSS DVDs.

But you need to make sure is it legal to rip DVDs in your country.

Or you have a check on these:

http://www.macworld.com/article/2029204/when-handbrake-wont-rip-your-dvds.html
http://www.videoconverterfactory.com/tips/handbrake-not-working.html

Hope these can help you out of this trouble. Good luck.